# url in scss files using raw in Webpack not working

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, webpack

I am currently working on an Angular 2 project, using webpack.

I am using the same kind of configuration as
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#loaders

I have an application-wide file scss (styles.scss), located in ./public/scss/styles.scss which is correctly linked in my index.html after webpacking.

```
<link href="/app.27a803de076ae294258e.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Other scss files (located in src/app) are component-scoped styles, they are loaded as string via raw loader, and inlined in "style" tag.

SVG files are managed via file-loader, they are copied into an "assets" output folder, and renamed with a hash.

For an unknown reason, all svg files mentioned in component-scoped styles via 'url()' are not found by the application, as if they were not required during the webpack step. They do not appear in the output assets folder. The 'url()' statement is not modified.

I would expect these lines would be replaced by a "require ..." and that require would trigger the file loader used for svg.

Here are my loaders from the webpack.config.js :

```
loaders: [
{
  test: /\.ts$/,
  loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
},
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'html'
},
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')
},
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
  loaders: ['raw', 'sass?sourceMap']
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
  loader: 'raw'
},
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico|otf)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
}
]
```

Here is an example of one component scss files :

```
.back-button {
  background: url(public/images/back.svg) no-repeat left;
  width: 16px;
  height: 19px;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

If I move the content of this .scss in the main file styles.scss, the image is correctly added to the assets folder, and the content of the url() is correctly replaced :

```
.back-button {
    background: url(/assets/back.be6884cba01794a64105228e8e25ce66.svg) no-repeat 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 19px;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I supposed it has something to do with the fact that component scss are loaded inline in the style tag.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: could you clarify your question a bit?  Specifically, I'm not sure what you mean by, "If I move these css class using url() in styles.scss, everything works fine.".  Could you show an example of what you do to make it work?

Comment: I've added more information to the question, thanks for your time :)

Comment: have you tried reversing the order of the loaders at all?  e.g. so that the svg loader comes before any scss processing?

Comment: yes, not better :(